# Tug of War Python Game

Tags: python, canvas, input

I'm trying to make a tug of war game but I'm running into one issue. I don't know how to change the x value without importing pygame.  All I need is that whenever 'z' is pressed x moves left 5 and when 'm' is pressed it moves right 5.

```
import simplegui
import random
import sys

x = 500
y = 200
num = 0


def draw_handler(canvas):
 global x
 global y
 global num
 color = "RGB(15, 69, 320)"


 x = x + num
 if (x >= 750):
    print ("Red Wins")
    quit()
 if (x <= 250):
    print ("Blue Wins")
    quit()


 canvas.draw_polygon([(0,0),(500,0),(500,500),(0,500)], 2, "Blue", "Blue")
 canvas.draw_polygon([(500,0),(500,500),(1000,0),(500,1000)], 2, "Red", "Red")
 canvas.draw_polygon([(0,0),(250,200),(0,400)], 2, "Black", "Red")
 canvas.draw_polygon([(1000,0),(750,200),(1000,400)], 2, "Black", "Blue")
 #Finish Line - canvas.draw_polygon([(199,0),(201,0),(199,1000),(201,1000)], 2, "Black", "Black")
 canvas.draw_polygon([(0,199),(0,201),(1000,199),(1000,201)], 2, "White", "Black") 
 canvas.draw_line((500,0),(500,500), 5, ("Black"))
 canvas.draw_line((0,0),(0,1000), 5, ("Black"))
 canvas.draw_line((0,0),(1000,0), 5, ("Black"))
 canvas.draw_line((0,400),(1000,400), 5, ("Black"))
 canvas.draw_line((1000,0),(1000,400), 5, ("Black"))

 canvas.draw_circle((x, y), 30, 20, "Black", "White")
 canvas.draw_circle((x, y), 80, 1, "Black")
 canvas.draw_circle((x, y), 90, 1, "Black")
 canvas.draw_circle((x, y), 100, 1, "Black")
 canvas.draw_circle((x, y), 120, 1, "Black")


 for i in range (1,1):
    print""
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Go", 1000, 400)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw_handler)
frame.set_canvas_background("Red")
frame.start()
```

Code updates [here](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user42_QcwDGVgeNpMFwwc.py).

Comment: Please include your code in your question - otherwise someone is going to come around and close it without a second thought. Also you should probably take a look at [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop to keep asking for input, and then process that input within the loop and redraw the canvas with each iteration. I know that'd probably be a pain, as they would also have to press enter, but that's probably what you'd have to do. Hope this helps!